# Field Calculator runs without error, but does not populate desired fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have merged numerous datasets that have the same attributes in different fields. I have TotalAcres, Total_Acres_Burned, TTL_ACRS, etc... I am trying to use field calculator to populate one field (TotalAcres) with all the acres values from the varying fields.

Using ArcMap 10.4.1 and python as parser.

Here is my code

```
def updateAcres ( TTL_ACRES, TotalAcres, ContrAcres, FIRE_SIZE, Field9, 
Total_Acres_Burned):
  if TTL_Acres > 0:
    TotalAcres = TTL_Acres
  elif ContrAcres > 0:
    TotalAcres = ContrAcres
  elif FIRE_SIZE > 0:
    TotalAcres = FIRE_SIZE
  elif Field9 > 0:
    TotalAcres = Field9
  elif Total_Acres_Burned > 0:
    TotalAcres = Total_Acres_Burned
  else: 
    return TotalAcres
```

Then my CodeBlock is:
TotalAcres=
  !TotalAcres!

It runs without throwing an error but it does not populate TotalAcres with the value from any of the other Acres fields.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the return method to write the new data to the field.

Pre-logic script code:

```
def updateAcres ( TTL_ACRES, TotalAcres, ContrAcres, FIRE_SIZE, Field9, 
    Total_Acres_Burned):
      if TTL_Acres > 0:
        return TTL_Acres
      elif ContrAcres > 0:
        return ContrAcres
      elif FIRE_SIZE > 0:
        return FIRE_SIZE
      elif Field9 > 0:
        return Field9
      elif Total_Acres_Burned > 0:
        return Total_Acres_Burned
      else: 
        return TotalAcres
```

function to call:

```
updateAcres(!TTL_ACRES!, !TotalAcres!, !ContrAcres!, !FIRE_SIZE!, !Field9!, 
!Total_Acres_Burned!)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This code turned every row in TotalAcres to NULL. Where am I missing how to assign the values from the other acres fields to TotalAcres?

Comment: are your field names spelled correctly in the function

Comment: @sparky i think you are confusing Code Block with the calling of the function and need to switch them.

Comment: @Bera Yes I guess I am. When you say switch them what are you referring to? Do I need a CodeBlock for this?

Comment: Yes. Look at this example, and the screenshot a bit higher: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0

Comment: I appreciate all the help, but I still don't see why TotalAcres, the field I want to populate is all NULL after the script runs. I feel as though I have matched up my code to all the examples I can find, but yet NULL is the only output I get. 

I have switched my CodeBlock to:

    updateAcres(!TTL_ACRES!, !TotalAcres!, !ContrAcres!, 
    !FIRE_SIZE!, !Field9!, 
    !Total_Acres_Burned!):

Comment: take a screen shot of your arcmap window and show us how you're inputing the function. also show us a screenshot of the attribute table

Comment: I added the screenshots of field calculator to the question. The attribute table is massive, but some rows have a value (they are all double) for TotalAcres, some have it in Total_Acres_Burned etc...

Comment: remove the colon (:) in the function calling also, it doesnt belong

Comment: Done, thanks. It still makes my desired field all NULL though unfortunately.

Comment: all fields being used even the new field are double type?

Comment: Yes they are all double. I am not trying to populate a new field, but an existing one. TotalAcres is a field in the dataset, but only contains an acreage value for 80 out of the 9300 records. The remaining values are spread throughout the other "Acre" fields. Is it better I create a new field and populate it with all the acre values from all the different fields?

Comment: Pyhton is case sensitive, TLL_ACRES is not the same as TLL_Acres. The code might fail on the first if statement

Comment: The code completes "successfully", it doesn't throw any errors, it just creates NULL as the output for every record I am trying to populate with an acreage value.

Comment: @sparky You are doing something incorrect. For example Spelling, indentation, case (LARGE or small letters), field type is text etc. You need to check all this again.

Comment: It was an indentation error of one space. It would be nice if Field Calculator allowed for tabs. Thank you for your help.